# How to get Windows To Go USB to work on ASUS / AMD hardware?

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, motherboard, windows-to-go

I have the following hardware:

- ASUS ROG Zenith Extreme motherboard
- AMD Threadripper 1950x
- Nvidia RTX 2070 graphics card
- USB 3.0 flash drive with Windows 10 Home To Go

I want to be able to adjust the RGB of my hardware with the ASUS Aura Sync software, which is only for Windows. So, I thought Windows To Go sounded like a nice option.

It took 8 hours to make a Windows 10 To Go drive using Rufus (GPT, UEFI, NTFS, 4096 byte cluster size), installed onto a 32 GB USB 3.0 flash drive. And I'm about 6 hours into waiting for it to boot when plugged into my system (there were multiple status messages for it setting up, and has been spinning on "Getting Ready" for hours, now).

I feel like this can't be right. Is there something I could have done wrong with trying to boot into the USB stick with Windows To Go on it? Or could there be hardware compatibility issues? Do I need to make sure to have drivers installed for my hardware, somewhere? Could using Rufus be a problem? etc.

I appreciate any help I can get. This is a slow iterative process and your help could greatly shorten that for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I feel like this can't be right

It can if your USB write speed is low (and yes, your write speed may be low even if the manufacturer advertises something like 100 MB/s *read* speed).

To be able to use Windows To Go without it slowing down to a crawl, you should use a USB 3.0 drive that has a write speed of at least 65 MB/s (higher if you can). And this needs to apply to random writes as well, as you may have a drive that's is great for sequential writes, but completely falls apart in terms of speed for random writes, which Windows very much require to be able to run at a decent speed.

Anything else, and especially the write speeds you get with regular cheap USB 3.0 flash drive is going to result in exactly the issues you encountered. And of course you need to make sure that the computer you are using it with does effectively support USB 3.0 speeds (as you'll also see the same issue if, for instance, you plug a super fast USB 3.0 drive on a USB 2.0 port).

For a long time, Windows actually restricted the creation of Windows To Go drives to *"certified"* flash drives, that met a specific standard in terms of write speed. And that is because unless you have a drive with a high enough write speed, the whole experience is going to be dreadful.

In summary, if you plan on creating a Windows To Go drive, you shouldn't consider that  any random USB 3.0 device will do, but ensure that the drive you use has a high enough read **and write** speed, and especially in terms of random access, as Windows does an awful lot of random writing to the system drive when it runs...

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, Akeo. According to another SuperUser conversation I found, I should get a USB with at least 70 MB/s write speed. The one I'm using is 5 MB/s, so that's definitely the speed culprit.

While on this though, I was able to boot in (finally), but I encounter the following sequence of events: Select language screen -> "Why did my PC restart? ... we think an update will help ..." -> Choose WiFi -> "Just a moment..." and spinning symbol... ~30m or so until unwanted computer restart.

I'm wondering if you think this could be drivers I don't have installed, or the speed?

Comment: I'd place my finger on the speed. You are literally wasting your time if your drive's write speed is 5 MB/s. It's absolutely not worth attempting to troubleshoot potential issues if your OS is slow as hell.